# change build variable with powershell not working

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

I want to change the tfs variable `BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME` while building, using this powershell script in my build step:

```
##vso[build.sourcebranch]master
```

This doesn't throw errors, but is not working either?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to change that? It's informational, not functional. Changing this variable won't change the branch that's being built. What is your objective?

Comment: I want to fake my tfs branch name - while building. This should not change the actual branch - just the tfs variable bevore the build ends.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: # is the comment character in Powershell - everything following it is ignored. Have you tried removing the ##?

Comment: You need quotes around `##vso` commands or PowerShell sees them as comments: `"##vso[build.sourcebranch]master"`

Comment: @RichMoss The syntax is (kind of) correct, Powershell is run from a Shell that interprets the `##vso` commands that are sent to the PS Console output.

Comment: @JamesC. At least in Azure DevOps' PowerShell 2.0 task, the quotes do not look required.  I just tried using a set task for a variable that worked without them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax to change any environment variable in Azure DevOps is:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=someVar]varValue"
```

So in your case, if you want to "fake" the source branch:

```
$fakeBranch = "shayki"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=build.sourcebranch]$fakeBranch"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=build.sourcebranchname]$fakeBranch"
```

The variables before:

[image]

The script:

[image]

The variables after:

[image]